# Remove link from dynamic link firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links

In iOS the listener from dynamic link always called and not leave the content the dynamic link in react-native. has how to remove the link from dynamic link firebase react-native.